# X-Cart Login Session

Tags: php, session, authentication, x-cart

I'm currently using X-Cart and have some employees (each has an X-Cart administration account). I also develop some custom PHP webpages (not X-Cart modules) which require my employees to login before they can access those webpages. I want my employees to use their existing X-Cart accounts to login.

For example, whenever my employees access custom webpages, if they're already logged in to X-Cart, they should be fine. If not, they should be redirected to X-Cart's admin login page.

My question is: How can my PHP scripts check if users are already logged in to X-Cart? I tried to include auth.php but I got the error message **"Can not initiate application! Please check configuration."**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Creating secure admin pages is pretty simple:

1. create new page in ROOT/admin/my_new_app.php
2. start your code with:

   ```
   /* My new App is secure */
   require './auth.php';
   require $xcart_dir.'/include/security.php';

   /* Put your App code in here... */


   /* You may (and you should) end with assigning main template as:
   $my_main = 'my_new_app';
   $location[] = array('New App!', '/admin/my_new_app.php');


   /* But then you need to go and edit YOUR_SKIN/single/home.tpl and add this:

   {elseif $main eq "my_new_app"}
   {include file="admin/my_new_app.tpl"}

   and you need to create your template file: admin/my_new_app.tpl 
   */
   ```

And that's it. If you are not an admin, you will get redirected to Login page (administration area).

There is one important note here: You **can not use post variables in your app without a real form on page**. You have to create a form, than xcart will create a hidden input field `_formid` (and it will have some hashed value, such as: `20b8e92504d1908bb1e3a264b9169f1e`). Once you have it, you can use AJAX and post variables, each time including `_formid` and its value.

The reason I am telling you this is strange message you get: `Can not initiate application! Please check configuration`. It does not come from x-Cart, my guess is: your app tries to post, but gets no response (missing `_formid`).